# Volume in a manifold and wedge product

Tags: integration, manifolds, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let's say we have some 4D maniforld $M$ in which the differential volume is given by Hodge's star $\star$ as

$$
dV :=\star\ 1 = \sqrt{|g|}\ dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3
$$

Where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor on $M$

Now, this $dV$ should be equal to the usually $dv$ given as

$$
dv = \sqrt{|g|}\ dx^0dx^1dx^2dx^3
$$

since both of them are the same concept, represent the same quantity. But since the wedge product is define as

$$
dx\wedge dy = \frac{1}{2}(dx\otimes dy - dy\otimes dx)
$$

I don't see how $dV$ and $dv$ are equal and moreover I don't understand quite well the importance of $\otimes$ in the wedge's definition. What would be the difference betweeen integrating a function $f(x, y)$ with $dx\otimes dy$ instead of $dy\otimes dx$? And how to prove $dV = dv$?

Comment: The first $dV$ is an actual differential form whereas the second $dv$ is just a notation, kind of like how writing the derivative as a fraction is just a notation. There is absolutely no reason they should be "equal".

Comment: @NinadMunshi With respect to your comment, if they are not equal then which one is the volume because if we are dealing with $\mathbb{R}^3$ the definition of the volumen is not up to us, it has to give the physical volume, and as far as I know it is normally used $dv$ and not $dV$. And regarding my second question: what is the difference between $\int dx\otimes dy\ f(x, y)$ and $\int dy\otimes dx\ f(x, y)$?

Comment: I think you mixing up a view things here. $dv$ is absolutely meaningless as was pointed out. The volume of any given (measurable) set $V$ is its integral $\int_V dx = vol(V)$. Now, to actually calculate it, we often seek a parameterization of that objection $V$ and then use the transformation theorem to get to something that we can calculate. Here this determiant $g$ comes into play. But $dx$ and $dV$ is mathematical undefined as stand alone objections.

Comment: @hal4math So we know that in 3D the volumen is $vol(V) = \int_V dxdydz, \ g = 1$ but we define $dV = (1/3!)\epsilon_{ijk}(dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes dx^k)$ which in principle has nothing to do with $dxdydz$ and we call it volmen when it couldn't be it. I'm totally confused

Comment: There are no tensor products! But wedge products $\wedge$. That is very very crucial, here! Also we call $dV$ a volume **form**,  since this is a map! Not a number! May I ask what reference you using?

Comment: The importance of the tensor product is quite frankly that the wedge product is a tensor. Yet it is antisymmetric. The definition makes sure of that: $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$. I am not sure what integration with respect to any tensor should be. (I repost because I mist the minus sign.)

Comment: I still think this is of course a very meaningful question and of course there is a reason why there is the word *volume* in that definition. And there is also a connection with what you are asking. But there are also a lot of conceptual and technical things involved. So given an "easy" answer is quite difficult, especially when it is not clear what you already know and what not. So for example are you concerned with general manifolds or submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Do you know how to define for a $n$-form $\omega$ on a $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ the expression $\int_M \omega$ ?

Comment: @hal4math Yes, I think I know all that so don't hesitate to give a more or less complex answer

Comment: then maybe take $M = \mathbb{R}^4$ with the usual metric $g$ and compute for $Q = (0,1)^4 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ what $\int_Q dV$ would be, where $dV = \sqrt(|g|) dx^1 \wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3 \wedge x^4$.

Comment: @hal4math In class I was told that to compute it you do $\int dV = \int \sqrt{|g|}\ dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4 = \int \sqrt{|g|}\ dx^1dx^2dx^3dx^4 = \int dv$ so I will not see the difference among $dv$ and $dV$. My professor said that $\int_M\omega = \sum_{\{\phi\}}\int_{\phi(M)}h(x)dx^1···dx^n$ for a n-D maninfold with charts $\phi$ and n-forms $\omega = h(x)dx^1\wedge ···\wedge dx^n$. So you can see why I don't get any of this

Comment: Okay, I think then we can sattle this easily now and are actually  back to the beginning. What you have on the right $\int dv$ is the Lebesgue (or Riemann integral) and $dv$ is really just a symbol! So in terms of Riemann integral $\int dv$ will be some series, but $dv$ alone has no precise meaning. Where as for the Lebesgue integral $v$ would be measure, but  again $dv$ has no meaning on its own. Now $dV$ very much has its own precise definition, that is $dV $ is a differential form. So you can calculate with it, make manipulations, e.g. take a derivative or take the Hodge star etc.

Comment: @hal4math So, if I got you right, the idea is to work with $dV$ for derivatives and any other operations but when it comes to integration we just change the wedge products ($dx\wedge dy$) by the usually one ($dxdy$) obtaining the normal Riemann/Lebesgue integral

Comment: In the very basic case when integrating (!) over an set of the $\mathbb{R}^n$, then yes! Of course this has much much wider applications. For example when $M$ is not  just an submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which by the way your definition of the integral assumes) but a proper "abstract" manifold (which is used in general relativity for example) . Also, differential forms are coordinate free! Also all the divergence theorems (Stoke's theorems) look the same in any dimension $\int_Q d\omega = \int_{\partial Q} \omega$. So it is a very useful generalization of calculus in $\mathbb{R}^n$.